# Updating the region behind a resized window

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, resize

We have a fairly complex GUI, so when certain windows are resized their Redraw() is set to false till the operation is completed. The problem with this is that if the OS "Show window content while dragging" setting is checked, when decreasing the window's size the windows behind it are not repainted. This means I have to force the repaint myself so the remains of the resized window are deleted. I have no problem getting the dimensions of the region that was uncovered. What I'm looking for is best way to cause all windows within that region to repaint their part.

Not being much of a GUI programmer, I can traverse the uncovered region and list the windows in it. Then, I can ask each one of them to repaint its part. But I'm quite certain there has to be a better way to do this...

It is worth mentioning the app is written in PowerBuilder. This means I can call whatever Win32 function I'd like, but have limited control over the GUI behavior and the message handling. If there's a better way to prevent the window's content resize from being visible, or there's a way to make a non-redrawn window clean after itself, I'd love to hear it (just have the limitations above in mind).

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what version of PowerBuilder you are working in?  I do resizing all the time and never run into issues like you are describing.

Maybe you can lay out some more detail on why you need to set your redraws to false within the PowerBuilder environment.

Hope I can help.